# Where are the Crowbar spawn locations in Shadow Raid?

Tags: payday-2

Where are the spawn locations for he Crowbar mission item in the Shadow Raid heist?  And do the locations differ based on difficulty?

I've played through a couple times on *Hard* and there is always a Crowbar on the left side (harbor side) roof, but I've never seen one there on *Very Hard*.

[image: Crowbar on the Harbor side roof]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Spawn locations of the crowbars are randomised, there are many locations where you can find them.

Some locations off the top of my head:

- Sewers, Right at first cross intersection
- Kitchen
- Shelves outside security room
- 1st floor, doorway leading to back room (with computers) next to the stairs
- Elevated red container at back right of compound

I think there are more but these are the ones I know about and regularly check.

Comment: Are the locations associated with difficulty?  Like I said in the question, I always find a Crowbar on the roof on Normal and Hard, but have never seen it there on Very Hard or Overkill

Comment: I think so, I've noticed that I never see the crowbar in that position (screenshot) when I play overkill/deathwish. I don't know for sure but it is possible that the difficulty changes the spawns. On Overkill/deathwish most of the crowbars are found inside the compound and warehouse rather than in places that can be found outside (in my experience).

Comment: On Normal and Hard, there is the crowbar on the roof as in the screenshot. On harder difficulties, it instead spawns in the sewer as MistaGiggles noted. Both of these locations are guaranteed spawns on their difficulties (as is the kitchen spawn on all difficulties). The rest of the possible locations that I am aware of are random.